# Programatically setting control properties vs. using designer

Tags: user-interface, ide

Often, when I'm looking for information of how to set certain properties of controls (I'm using Visual Studio primarily, but this question does apply to any IDE), the examples I find normally involve programatically setting said properties.

Here's an example, using the DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle property on MSDN:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So my question is: is it better for a programmer to modify these properties by code, or is it better to use the IDE itself to change them via the properties pane? I realize that doing it the latter way will result in auto-generated code anyway, but it will be "somewhere else" in relation to the main bulk of user-generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements. If the app you are developing is planned to be dynamic, then it is a good idea to do it the way it is described in the reference you provided. For example, you may create a class containing the method which will set the basic settings of the gridview, so on every page you may just call this method and pass to it the gridview as a parameter instead of repeating setting the grid properties on every page.